# Handling Symbols with PHP xml parser

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I'm writing a xml to text file script with PHP's xml parser. I delimit attributes with @ signs and data with | symbols, what I've noticed is when I open the text file is that symbols are seen as their own data.

```
i.e. <equation valid="yes">For this theorem assume X < Y and Z & A = 0</equation>
should have output @yes@ |For this theorem assume X < Y and Z & A = 0|
but instead I have @yes@ |For this theorem assume X| |<| |Y| and Z | |&| | A = 0|
```

so what I believe is going on is that any symbols that rely on &[a-z]+; or &[0-9]+; gets treated as different data between the two tags. I tried `preg_replace("/&([a-z]+);/","\1",$data)` and the same for numbers to just have the letters/numbers there for me to format later but that didn't seem to do anything. How can I get xml parser to recognize those symbols as part of the data?

Edit1: I've just now also tried replacing all & with \& but that didn't do anything either, I just get backslashes before my data delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are asking about special characters in a string?
If so you need to use the ascii equivilent, i.e.

```
    For this theorem assume X < Y and Z & A = 0
    Becomes
    For this theorem assume X &lt; Y and Z &amp; A &#61; 0
```

Comment: Right, that's the problem. I don't think I've explained it well, when php's xml parser hits the '&' symbol it believes it's in a different data node than the one previous, I'm not sure what I should change so it can recognize the &[a-z]+/[0-9]+; regex as not a new data node.

Comment: What encoding are you specifying in the XML doc?

Comment: Is it possible you saved it as double-byte? Try specifying UTF-16 as the encoding type.

Comment: The xmlparser throws an error, I think it only accepts UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, and US-ASCII encodings. I've regexed all the ampersands to the word AMP as a temporary fix just so I can keep testing my code, but I'd love to hear the correct solution.